# Using selenium refresh page when the page times out, when it doesn't continue with test

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Currently my logic is that check the page if its loading than continue the loop. If can't find the loading page than check if the element for the completed loaded page is there if so break the loop. If the driver.find_element errors then check if the page timed out by some element that is only on the timeout page. If it has text content that is indicative of a timeout than refresh the page.

However, this logic doesn't work at all, the page just keeps refreshing even before timeout. So the page never gets to fully load.

```
attempt = 0
    while True:
        try:
            loading = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id=\"loadimg1\"]/font/i/text()[2]")
            if loading.get_attribute('textContent') == 'Thank you for your patience.':
                print("Continued")
                continue
            else:
                success_html = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//iframe)[1]")
                if success_html.is_displayed():
                    print("Broken")
                    break
        except Exception:
            failed = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/i/a")
            if failed.get_attribute('textContent') == 'Broad Gene Set Enrichment Analysis (GSEA)':
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.refresh()
                print("Refreshed")
        finally:
            attempt +=1
            print(attempt)
```

I tried this configuration where we check for the timeout screen first and if can't find it then see if page is loading, if so continue. If not check if finished loading and break the loop. However this has the same problem where it'll continue to refresh even if the page completes loading. Not sure what to do here or if there's a better way to structure this.

```
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        try:
            failed = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/i/a")
            if failed.get_attribute('textContent') == 'Broad Gene Set Enrichment Analysis (GSEA)':
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.refresh()
                print("Refreshed")
        except Exception:
            loading = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@id=\"loadimg1\"]/font/i/text()[2]")
            if loading.get_attribute('textContent') == 'Thank you for your patience.':
                print("Continued")
                continue
            else:
                success_html = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="(//iframe)[1]")
                if success_html.is_displayed():
                    print("Broken")
                    break
        finally:
            attempt +=1
            print(attempt)
```